# How to send a Push Notification from windows Phone 7 to .NET Winform Application

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7

please forgive me for this idiot question. I understood that we can send push notifications to windows phone 7.

Like, in our case we sent the Raw push notification to our application running on Windows Phone 7 and based on that notification the application did some work. Now after that the user did some action which is suppose to communicate back to our main Winform application.

How can we achiver this functionality? How can we receive the notification back from Windows Phone 7 to .NET Winform application.

Can anybody share thier experience.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Push notifications can only be sent **TO** a WP7 app.

If you want to call another app (on another machine/server) you'll have to make a HTTP (or socket) request from the WP7 app. If you want that to go to an app on a PC you'll need to route the message via a web endpoint. The format, sending and delivery of such messages are entirely up to you. There is no service currently available in the SDK to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a http based wcf service that your windows phone app can call. And let the wcf service push data to a message queue(MSMQ, RabbitMQ) which your window form will be listening to for response